# nservicebus can handle db client to msmq backend?

Tags: nservicebus

I wonder is nservicebus pub/sub or other type of app can handle db client to msmq server.

For example I have a desktop client app. using db queue and i want to send message to server using msmq message queue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this article about interop with SQL Server: http://andreasohlund.net/2010/09/03/event-based-interop-with-service-broker/.  There exists an Oracle AQS transport as well if you are using Oracle.

The article describes how to setup a bridge between the DB queue and MSMQ.